# Client file not importing properly discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to import parts of the file bot.js and am calling it Client

```
const Topgg = require('@top-gg/sdk')
const { message } = require('./bot')
const Client = require('./bot')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const app = express()
const port = 1858
const webhook = new Topgg.Webhook("fattypatty")

app.post("/dblwebhook", webhook.listener(async vote => {
   console.log(`${vote.user} has voted me`)
   const webhook2 = new Discord.WebhookClient('866550068798947337', 'X0EeUAXvOHRW7s3o81QR_pZy4AnUc7mKHtrSzwTezIffPjEWYK9wQ3V62p6Aff1-aJ-c')
   webhook2.send(`<@${vote.user}> has voted and recieved`)
   const user = vote.user
   const newuser = client.users.fetch(user)
   client.economy.addBal(user, 5000)   

}))
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Webhook Port On`)
 })
```

Client is the bot being imported from discordjs and the bot.js file. When i try something like Client.users.fetch(), I get a error that I can't fetch from null.

Here is my Client.js file:
https://pastebin.com/kA39fsPV

I am trying to use parts of it like Client.users and Client.economy.addBal() which are functions in the client file.

They both aren't in any folders

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly imported the `EconomyClient` class as `Client` (notice: capital C) in your code. However, you're trying to use an object called `client` (lowercase C) which does not exist yet.

It seems like you forgot to instantiate the `client` object—insert the following line:

```js
const client = new Client();
```

[[Relevant docs]](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#logging-in-to-discord)

Comment: So if i do new Client it doesnt work, but if I do 
const EconomyClient = require(`./bot.js`);
const client = new EconomyClient();

Everything imports correctly, but I get the error that 
TypeError: Client is not a constructor

Comment: Put in `Discord.Client()` instead

Comment: But I am trying to access my bot.js file and not create a new client

Comment: Extending the Client class isn't a good idea since it wasn't designed to be. Try making a wrapper instead, having your Economy class *contain* a Discord client instead of *being* one.